# Nginx+phpFPM Rewrite rules not working

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, php

I got FreeBSD 9.1 VPS with Nginx+phpFPM installed. The problem in rewrite rules for urls for phpBB forum. Tried to insert some configs and none working. Orginal .htaccess:

```
# REMEBER YOU ONLY NEED TO STARD MOD REWRITE ONCE
RewriteEngine On
# Uncomment the statement below if you want to make use of
# HTTP authentication and it does not already work.
# This could be required if you are for example using PHP via Apache CGI.
# RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
# REWRITE BASE
RewriteBase /
# HERE IS A GOOD PLACE TO FORCE CANONICAL DOMAIN
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost/forum$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/forum/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

# DO NOT GO FURTHER IF THE REQUESTED FILE / DIR DOES EXISTS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]
#####################################################
# PHPBB SEO REWRITE RULES ALL MODES
#####################################################
# AUTHOR : dcz www.phpbb-seo.com
# STARTED : 01/2006
#################################
# FORUMS PAGES
###############
# FORUM INDEX REWRITERULE WOULD STAND HERE IF USED. "forum" REQUIRES TO BE SET AS FORUM INDEX
# RewriteRule ^forum\.html$ /index.php [QSA,L,NC]
# FORUM ALL MODES
RewriteRule ^(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /viewforum.php?f=$2&start=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
# TOPIC WITH VIRTUAL FOLDER ALL MODES
RewriteRule ^(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)/(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /viewtopic.php?f=$2&t=$4&start=$6 [QSA,L,NC]
# TOPIC WITHOUT FORUM ID & DELIM ALL MODES
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]*)/?(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /viewtopic.php?forum_uri=$1&t=$3&start=$5 [QSA,L,NC]
# PHPBB FILES ALL MODES
RewriteRule ^resources/[a-z0-9_-]+/(thumb/)?([0-9]+)$ /download/file.php?id=$2&t=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
# PROFILES THROUGH USERNAME
RewriteRule ^member/([^/]+)/?$ /memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&un=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
# USER MESSAGES THROUGH USERNAME
RewriteRule ^member/([^/]+)/(topics|posts)/?(page([0-9]+)\.html)?$ /search.php?author=$1&sr=$2&start=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
# GROUPS ALL MODES
RewriteRule ^(group|[a-z0-9_-]*-g)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /memberlist.php?mode=group&g=$2&start=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
# POST
RewriteRule ^post([0-9]+)\.html$ /viewtopic.php?p=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
# ACTIVE TOPICS
RewriteRule ^active-topics(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=active_topics&start=$2&sr=topics [QSA,L,NC]
# UNANSWERED TOPICS
RewriteRule ^unanswered(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=unanswered&start=$2&sr=topics [QSA,L,NC]
# NEW POSTS
RewriteRule ^newposts(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=newposts&start=$2&sr=topics [QSA,L,NC]
# UNREAD POSTS
RewriteRule ^unreadposts(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=unreadposts&start=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
# THE TEAM
RewriteRule ^the-team\.html$ /memberlist.php?mode=leaders [QSA,L,NC]
# HERE IS A GOOD PLACE TO ADD OTHER PHPBB RELATED REWRITERULES

# FORUM WITHOUT ID & DELIM ALL MODES
# THESE FOUR LINES MUST BE LOCATED AT THE END OF YOUR HTACCESS TO WORK PROPERLY
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)(-([0-9]+))\.html$ /viewforum.php?forum_uri=$1&start=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ /viewforum.php?forum_uri=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
# FIX RELATIVE PATHS : FILES
RewriteRule ^.+/(style\.php|ucp\.php|mcp\.php|faq\.php|download/file.php)$ /$1 [QSA,L,NC,R=301]
# FIX RELATIVE PATHS : IMAGES
RewriteRule ^.+/(styles/.*|images/.*)/$ /$1 [QSA,L,NC,R=301]
# END PHPBB PAGES
#####################################################
```

Sample config created in nginx:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.domain.com;
        rewrite ^ http://domain.com$request_uri?;
error_log /var/log/www/domain.com/nerror.log;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.com;
        server_name_in_redirect off;
        root /usr/local/www/domain.com;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        location ~* ^.+\.(ico|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp)$ {
          expires 30d;
        }

         location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        rewrite ^/(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /viewforum.php?f=$2&start=$4 last;
        rewrite ^/(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)/(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /viewtopic.php?f=$2&t=$4&start=$6 last;
        rewrite ^/post([0-9]+)\.html$ /viewtopic.php?p=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)/(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /viewtopic.php?f=$2&t=$4&start=$6 last;
        rewrite ^/([a-z0-9_-]*)/?(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /viewtopic.php?forum_uri=$1&t=$3&start=$5 last;
        rewrite ^/resources/[a-z0-9_-]+/(thumb/)?([0-9]+)$ /download/file.php?id=$2&t=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/post([0-9]+)\.html$ /viewtopic.php?p=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/active-topics(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=active_topics&start=$2&sr=topics last;
        rewrite ^/unanswered(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=unanswered&start=$2&sr=topics last;
        rewrite ^/newposts(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=newposts&start=$2&sr=topics last;
        rewrite ^/unreadposts(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=unreadposts&start=$2 last;
        }
           location ~ /(config\.php|common\.php|cache|files|images/avatars/upload|includes|store) {
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                    # fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
                    fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT    $document_root;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
  fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
  fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
  fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
  fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
  fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
  fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
  fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
  fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
  fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
  fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;

        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;` before all the rewrite rules. If `try_files` succeeds, it stops there.

To fix this, you have a couple options.

1) break out all your rewrites into location blocks, following this format:

```
location ~* /(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ {
    rewrite ^ /viewforum.php?f=$2&start=$4 last;
}
```

or 2) add a `@rewrite` block like so:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/$ /index.php last;
    rewrite ^/(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /viewforum.php?f=$2&start=$4 last;
    rewrite ^/(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)/(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /viewtopic.php?f=$2&t=$4&start=$6 last;
    rewrite ^/post([0-9]+)\.html$ /viewtopic.php?p=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)/(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /viewtopic.php?f=$2&t=$4&start=$6 last;
    rewrite ^/([a-z0-9_-]*)/?(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /viewtopic.php?forum_uri=$1&t=$3&start=$5 last;
    rewrite ^/resources/[a-z0-9_-]+/(thumb/)?([0-9]+)$ /download/file.php?id=$2&t=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/post([0-9]+)\.html$ /viewtopic.php?p=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/active-topics(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=active_topics&start=$2&sr=topics last;
    rewrite ^/unanswered(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=unanswered&start=$2&sr=topics last;
    rewrite ^/newposts(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=newposts&start=$2&sr=topics last;
    rewrite ^/unreadposts(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=unreadposts&start=$2 last;
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this so it might not be perfect or the best, but you should be able to tweak it from here.

Comment: Tried 2 configs as you suggested, none work for me. Hope i did some mistakes only. 
First method:  http://pastebin.com/JT2LaSPn
   
Second method: http://pastebin.com/zciC3Stv

Comment: Sorry it's not working. I'll give it a better look a little later, I need to set up a test instance of phpbb.

Comment: To be more specific I add that testing on URL - tangoresults.com. Here i got phpBBSEO enabled. For example thread has non-sef url - http://tangoresults.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=3   which correspond to current -      http://tangoresults.com/topic3.html   phpBBSEO generated .htaccess http://pastebin.com/eLphHJN1 file which i adapted as http://pastebin.com/mZjJh8F9

Comment: Seems rewrites works fine for topic*.html, but not for forum*.html  Got rewrite log http://pastebin.com/VRTKCgVP

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the nginx conf file so it will act similarly to an apache htaccess multiview.

For phpbb seo, you'll want to add this location declaration at the bottom of your conf file:

```
#added the ability to do multiviews for subforums
    location ~ ^(.+)/$ {
    try_files $uri $1.html?$args;
}
```

That should allow you to have Search Engine Optimized forum links.

Hopefully this helps get you started.